# How to redirect request to different domain/ip:port with cookie setted?

Tags: networking, nginx-location, nginx-config

I was going to use *rewrite* or *return* to redirect a request to a different domain and change the url on the browser(because there will be other requests from another domain which cannot be proxied) but failed to transfer cookie, how could I achieve that?
Here are my nginx settings

```
server {
    listen 9000;
    server_name localhost;

    location /vuetify-blog {
        add_header Cookies $http_cookie;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://(another ip:port)/vuetify-blog redirect;
    }
}
```

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCOYg.jpg
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAf55.jpg
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov8Hr.jpg

I expected the cookie exist in redirected request header but it didn't.